# Instantiating classes with package-private constructors from outside modules

Tags: java

I would like to make use of a package-private constructor, to prevent the instantiation of a certain object from the outside. The only one who should be able to instantiate the class is a factory class, which resides in the same package.

My concerns are that if my application gets compiled and sealed, the only possible way to ever provide new classes with a package-private scope, which could be accessed by the same factory (or a why not a new implementation of the factory), would be to mimic the exact same path to the package in the project that references my sealed lib.

Though this is by no means impossible, I am just wondering if it should be considered a good practice. What do you think about package-private scope used in that sense?

Comment: I think this is the right, and only possible, way to do it with package-private scope. If you want to have your Factory class easily extendable, perhaps the use of interfaces would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

It should work this way. I don't have another way in mind to achieve this neither.

But, IMHO it is often not very constructive to do so. There might be corner cases to prohibit other-then-expected-usage, but in general I think you should try to establish the factory because its ease of use and convince people with that.
If your factory is not extendable, people may end up creating classes in "your" package just to access your classes like they want.